# how can I use the Button widget in python to place buttons in specific places on the screen?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

thanks for helping...
I would like to place a button using tkinter's Button function.
I am not exactly sure how to place a button though. I've actually put a button on the screen, using the pack() method, but am unsure of how to have more control over were it goes.  here is my code

```
main = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(main, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack() 
btn1 = Button (tk, text = "speak your name and click here!", command = moo_man)

btn1.pack()

btn1.place(bordermode = OUTSIDE, width = 270, height = 25)
```

say for example, I wanted to put the button in the top right corner.
Thanks, all help is appreciated!!

Comment: I forgot to say, this is Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place` has options for relative placement. You can combine absolute and relative positioning, so you want the *relative* X coordinate to be 1.0 (ie: all the way to the right) and the *absolute* Y coordinate to be zero. Also, you want the coordinate to represent the upper-right corner of the button so that it is in the upper right of the parent window:

```
bt1.place(relx=1.0, y=0, anchor="ne")
```

For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm

On a side note: you should consider using `pack` or `place` in almost all situations. `place` is useful for some edge cases, but for most situations it's the least useful geometry manager. `pack` and `grid` make your UI much easier to create and modify. They are worth taking time to learn.

Comment: I'm kinda new to programing, what do you mean by "relative"?

Comment: the anchor makes perfect sense, I love it when things make sense!!

Comment: @oboy: relative, as in how it relates to the parent window. A relative coordinate in place is a decimal - 0 means left edge, 1.0 means right edge, .5 means in the middle.

Comment: no matter what I do, the Button is always at the top of the screen, however, I can position the x coordinates

Comment: btn.place(relx = 0.5, y = 0.5, anchor = "n")

Comment: to place it in the middle of the screen.

Comment: the `y` parameter is an absolute number. You are telling it to be at absolute y coordinate .5. If you want `y` to be relative, use `rely`. I suggest you read http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm